# Custom domain for s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have S3 bucket called "mybucket". Files from there are available under following links:

1. `mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.jpg`
2. `s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/path/to/file.jpg`

I need custom domain for files served from s3. I added DNS CNAME record pointing to from `images.example.com` to `s3.amazonaws.com` (also tried `images.example.com -> mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com`).

In both cases when I try to GET `images.example.com/mybucket/path/to/file/jpg` (or `images.example.com/path/to/file.jpg`) I get S3 error like

```
Bucket 'images.example.com' does not exist
```

Is there any workaround for this or I have to change bucket name to `images.example.com`?

Comment: I'm actually trying to do the same but can't figure out how I need to work a file fetch , but can't use s3 link directly due to iot device restrictions , can you help with some sort of documentation

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to change the bucket name. The [virtual hosting docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html) specifically say (in the "Customizing Amazon S3 URLs with CNAMEs" section)

> The bucket name must be the same as the CNAME

Answer (score 0):

From what I've experienced, you just need to set the CNAME with name `images` and the value is `mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com` (your bucket location). You don't need to rename your bucket. Old but gold.