# Pointing `mydomain.com/images` to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

First time working with `AWS`, `S3` & `Lambda`, using `Laravel Vapor`. I have an `S3` bucket to host a few images for an app, and would like to understand if it is possible to replace:

```
https://my-bucket-name.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
```

with

```
https://subdomain.mydomain.com
```

My bucket contains an `images` folder, and I want to access the images as:

```
https://subdomain.mydomain.com/images/logo.png
```

This may be a basic question, but I have been unable to figure it out looking at AWS's Virtual Hosting docs for `S3`. Any pointers / suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom domain for s3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667252/custom-domain-for-s3-bucket)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=host+static+website+on+s3+domain

Comment: Hi @quentin, my issue is I have the domain currently being pointed to another `S3` bucket via `Laravel Vapor` and so there is a `cname` already in on my domain registrar to do this. So `subdomain.mydomain.com` points to an alias in AWS. How do I point the url + images path to S3? `subdomain.mydomain.com/images/`

Comment: Your s3 url does not looks like a static website. you could achieve this easily using cloudfront with s3.