# "cross domain javascript source file inclusion" reported by OWASP ZAP for trusted resource

Tags: http-headers, cross-domain, content-security-policy, nginx-config, owasp

My host is `www.example.com` and I'm serving html pages with URL `www.example.com/html-url.html`.
In these htmls I have included a javascript file from our S3 bucket say `bucket-name`.

The OWASP ZAP scan is raising a low level alert for this - Cross-Domain JavaScript Source File Inclusion
Evidence: `<script src="bucket-name/custom.js" type="text/javascript"/>`

**Question:** Is there any way that I can configure a list of trusted resources/URLs in configuration? I'm using NGINX server.
Please note that, for some reasons I need to get a clean vulnerability scan report.

I understand that there is this HTTP header "Content Security Policy" and on the official site it says "Content Security Policy (CSP) is an HTTP header that allows site operators fine-grained control over where resources on their site can be loaded from."

But I'm not sure if I can make use of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can [delegate custom domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667252/custom-domain-for-s3-bucket) for S3 bucket, for example subdomain `cdn.example.com` to avoid Cross-Domain JavaScript Source File.

I do not know what is "under the hood" of OWASP ZAP and is it possible to influence on OWASP ZAP alert above with CSP header, but CSP definitely should give additional points to security.

Answer (score 0):

A "clean vulnerability scan report" is desirable but I personally dont think it should be mandatory - web scanners report potential vulnerabilities so some may be false positives or even true positives that are not actually relevant for your situation.

In any case "bucket-name/custom.js" is not cross domain so this looks like a false positive. Have you updated ZAP? If so please raise this as an ZAP issue and we can fix it: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues